# How Expressjs decides which error handler to call. if we have multiple error handles

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

I am just curious to know that how express decides which error handler to call (next(err)), when we have multiple error handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple errorhandlers, they will be called in the order you put them in your `.use` statements. Every errorhandler has to do `next(err)` though in order to pass the error on.

Taken from expressjs documentation:

```
app.use(logErrors)
app.use(clientErrorHandler)
app.use(errorHandler)
```

As an example from the documentation:

```
function errorHandler (err, req, res, next) {
  if (res.headersSent) {
    return next(err)
  }
  res.status(500)
  res.render('error', { error: err })
}
```

So an error is beeing passed from handler to handler with the `next(err)` statement. And within that handler you decide what to do. You could for example check for a specific error and only act on that specific error.

[expressjs documentation for errorhandling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

Comment: I understand that.. but suppose error comes and now it is in logErrors body. now from here how it decides wheater it should call errorHandler or call logErrors. @sentinel

Comment: @hemant I added a little to the answer. You can't decide which errorhandler to call. The next(err) statement will call the handler that is the next one in the line. In this case the order would be: logErrors -> clientErrorHandler -> errorHandler

Comment: Actually, this behavior of express is garbage, there must be some sort of _local error handlers_, instead of always passing the errors to the *global* ones.